# How to consume RabbitMQ in WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, rabbitmq, wcf-binding

I have a scenerio,where a executable is the producer and WCF service is the consumer.

WCF service WorkFlow is as follows:

1)Service invokes the executable (producer), this executable is another process which produces the messages into RabbitMQ Queue.

2)Service has to consume the messages from the RabbitMQ Queue

3)Returns the data to client.

```
using RabbitMQ.Client;
using RabbitMQ.Client.Events;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace ConnectionServices
{

    public class Connection : IConnection
    {
        public string ConnectSite(string provider, string server, string siteName)
        {
            InvokeProducer(provider, server, siteName);
            string activeInstance = RunRabbitMQ();
            return activeInstance;

        }
        public void InvokeProducer(string provider, string server, string siteName)
        {
            string siteManagerExePath = @"C:\Users\mbmercha\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Producer\Producer\bin\Debug\Producer.exe";
            try
            {
                ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
                Process siteManagerProcess = new Process();
                startInfo.FileName = siteManagerExePath;
                startInfo.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3}", "-b ", provider, server, siteName);
                siteManagerProcess.StartInfo = startInfo;
                siteManagerProcess.Start();
                siteManagerProcess.WaitForExit();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
        }
        public string RunRabbitMQ()
        {
            var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost" };
            string activeInstance = null;
            using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
            using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
            {
                channel.QueueDeclare("DurableQueue", true, false, false, null);
                channel.ExchangeDeclare("DurableExchange", ExchangeType.Topic, true);
                channel.QueueBind("DurableQueue", "DurableExchange", "durable");
                var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);

                consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
                {
                    var body = ea.Body;
                    var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
                    activeInstance = message;
                };
                channel.BasicConsume(queue: "DurableQueue",
                                     autoAck: false,
                                     consumer: consumer);


            }
            return activeInstance;
        }
    }
}
```

So far service is able to invoke executable and messages are produced in the queue.

But service fails from step 2, it is returning null instead of actual message.
Can anybody suggest me what I am missing here?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: These two lines where `activeInstance` is used: `string activeInstance = null;` `return activeInstance;` You never set this variable.

Comment: It was my typo mistake.In actual code it is proper and still I am getting null @Reniuz

Comment: So please add the actual code. Now message must be null, but it can't because GetString() returns string.

Comment: I have edited the code @Reniuz

Comment: Your question has absolutely nothing to do with WCF.

Comment: `activeInstance` will be set only when event is raised. In this code you just subscribing to Receive event and getting out of the method with not set `activeInstance` variable. Debug, put breakpoints on `activeInstance = message` and `return activeInstance` and you see what happens.

Comment: I found that from WCF service, the event is not getting triggered.While the same code I tested with console application and the event is getting triggered and I am able to return the value. Can you help, why it is not able to trigger in WCF? @Reniuz

Comment: Maybe produces in service is dead. It might throw exception and you are not handling. Who could possibly know what apart you? Know one will answer that. There will be just blind shots.

Comment: Even I checked producer in WCF service, it is working fine.For consumer, what I found when I compared console application and WCF service is, console application was able to reach RabbitMQ server while WCF service was not able to reach.@Reniuz @Ricardo Peres

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're never setting `activeInstance` to anything except `null`.

You appear to be using the asynchronous API, which means that you're retrieving the message from RabbitMQ long after the `RunRabbitMQ` method call has completed... or you would be if you didn't immediately dispose of all the consumer machinery when returning.

If you want to retrieve messages synchronously - in this case, within a synchronous method call - you'll need to wait for a message to become available. For this, you'd want to use the 'pull API', which is `channel.BasicGet(...)`.

Comment: It was my typo mistake.In actual code it is proper and still I am getting null @yaakov

Comment: You still have the synchronicity issue - you're setting the variable from an event, but the event doesn't get fired before the method finishes.

Comment: I found that from WCF service, the event is not getting triggered.While the same code I tested with console application and the event is getting triggered and I am able to return the value. Can you help, why it is not able to trigger in WCF? @yaakov